# Check for installed application on client using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, activex

Can anyone suggest how to check whether an application is installed on client in ASP.Net application.

As asp.net runs on server, I believe it should be done using some client side scripting.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible if you can run an ActiveX component on your page -- a component that the end user will have to install on his machine, to give it permissions to read the Registry.

JavaScript itself (or VBScript) cannot read values from the Registry, and it cannot access the client PC's file system, so it cannot find out what is installed.